# Wave file compression

Tags: c#, audio

I have a RIFF wav file, for which the data at position 22 is `0x01` and 23 is `0x00`, indicating a mono file.

What I am not able to decipher is the compression format for this file. According to the wav format specification, as described [here](http://tiny.systems/software/soundProgrammer/WavFormatDocs.pdf), data at positions 20 and 21 should be able to describe the compression. That data is `0x21` and `0x72`.

I did find a list of WAV file compression format codes [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/143294/WAV-file-compression-format-codes), but am not able to understand what would be the exact code for my wave file and how to uncompress/ read the data.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CODEC number 0x7221 is not registered, so it's somebody's custom format.  Good luck with that.  Try GSpot.